# Why can't I access this created object in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object

I have a problem relating to this simple Java object creation.

My code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaDatiContabiliEnte", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvaDatiContabiliEnte(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {

    CodIbanEspanso ibanEspanso;

    Tid023Intervento progettoSelezionato = (Tid023Intervento) model.asMap().get("progettoSelezionato");
    System.out.println("INTO salvaDatiContabiliEnte, progettoSelezionato: " + progettoSelezionato.toString());

    Tid022Anagraficarup anagraficaRup = progettoSelezionato.getTid022Anagraficarup();               // Angrafica del RUP
    Tid018Entebeneficiario enteBeneficiario = progettoSelezionato.getTid018Entebeneficiario();      // Ente beneficiario

    DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    GestioneDatiContabiliForm gestioneDatiContabiliForm = new ObjectMapper().readValue(multipartRequest.getParameterMap().get("form")[0], GestioneDatiContabiliForm.class);

    if(gestioneDatiContabiliForm.getIban() != null) {       // Se l'IBAN inserito non è null ---> Se la regione non è il Friuli
        ibanEspanso = new CodIbanEspanso(gestioneDatiContabiliForm.getIban());  // Costruisce l'IBAN espanso a partire dal codice IBAN intero

    }

    return "blablabla";
}
```

As you can see, at the beginning of my method I declare a **CodIbanEspanso ibanEspanso** object and I don't initialize it by calling a constructor.

I then initialize it in this statement:

```
if(gestioneDatiContabiliForm.getIban() != null) {       // Se l'IBAN inserito non è null ---> Se la regione non è il Friuli
    ibanEspanso = new CodIbanEspanso(gestioneDatiContabiliForm.getIban());  // Costruisce l'IBAN espanso a partire dal codice IBAN intero
}
```

Using the debugger I see that it does enter in the if statement and it does check that the object fields are correctly initialized by its constructor.

But then, after the `if` statement, if I try to see the content of the **ibanEspanso** object (that I had initialized), Eclipse debugger give me this error message:

```
"ibanEspanso"    <error(s)_during_the_evaluation>   
ibanEspanso cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How is it possible? Why can it not be found if this object was initialized when the program entered the previous `if` statement? What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot dereference a pointer that is not guaranteed to be initialised to _something_. What happens when `...getIban() == null`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider what exactly mean? can you explain me it deeper?

Comment: I mean, when `gestioneDatiContabiliForm.getIban() == null` what value does `ibanEspanso` have? See [JLS §4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), "_A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used_".

Comment: If you try to use `ibanEspanso` you will get a compiler error, something like `ibanEspanso may not have been initialized`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because your reference is not initialised. You may try something like :

```
CodIbanEspanso ibanEspanso = null;
```

Answer (score -3):

`ibanEspanso` is never used after the if statement. put it somewhere after the if statement, anything would do:

```
System.out.println(ibanEspanso);
```

Comment: This isn't relevant, and given the OPs code this wouldn't compile.